# Python: only print stderr, not stdout, from subprocess.call()?

Tags: python, subprocess, stderr

I'm using Python's `subprocess.call` ([docs here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)) and I have a question about standard output.

I have the following command:

```
subprocess.call("wget http://google.com", shell=True)
```

It works great, but it prints the output of wget, so I get an absolute ton of wget output like:

```
--2013-06-28 08:54:47--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com... 173.194.41.100, 173.194.41.98, 173.194.41.97, ...
Connecting to google.com|173.194.41.100|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
.... etc
```

How can I change the call so it only prints anything if there is an error?

I have tried studying [the subprocess docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module), but I think I'm too inexperienced to figure it out for myself.

Comment: have you tried `urllib.urlretrieve()` or `urllib2.urlopen()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think the easiest way would be to use the '-q' option that 'wget' has. You can still catch error by looking at the return value.

Answer (score 1):

[`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Logging-and-Input-File-Options) normally reports *all* output on stderr, so redirecting stdout will not help with getting errors only.

You can either use `-nv` (non verbose) or `-q` (quiet) as options to wget, the difference being that `-q` does not even report errors while `-nv` reports errors or a single success line to stderr.

The return code is unchanged in both cases, so it can be used to detect any errors if that's the way you prefer.

EDIT: If you really just want to ignore *all* output from wget, you can redirect `stderr` and `stdout` to a null device;

```
import subprocess
import os

DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'wb')

subprocess.call("wget http://google.com/", stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL, shell=True)
```

In my Python 3.3.1 install, DEVNULL can be imported from subprocess instead, but I can't find documentation on exactly what version it was added in. The above works in both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to silence `wget` completely - not even report errors? For me the `-q` option does print a single line on success, I'm wondering if there's a way to print nothing at all.

Comment: Ah, just realised I can do `wget_output = subprocess.call(...)` and that doesn't print anything :)